# Remove outliers by 2 groups based on IQR in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called `df` as below (the actual data frame contains thousands of rows) where column `Category` has 3 unique values (A, B, C), and column `Gender` has 2 unique values (M,F):

[image]

I would like to remove outliers of `Value1` and `Value2` by `Category` and by `Gender` based on the IQR.

I have written the below function for flagging the outliers of a column based on the IQR :

```
import numpy as np

def outliers_iqr(column):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(column, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return np.where((column> upper_bound) | (column< lower_bound))
```

and so I then need to do something like this:

```
Value1_Outliers_Removed = df[~df.groupby(['Category', 'Gender'])['Value1'].apply(outliers_iqr)]

Value2_Outliers_Removed = df[~df.groupby(['Category', 'Gender'])['Value2'].apply(outliers_iqr)]
```

and then find and keep only the Id's of the intersection of `Value1_Outliers_Removed` and `Value2_Outliers_Removed`

The problem is that the code above for `Value1_Outliers_Removed` and `Value2_Outliers_Removed` does not work since I get the following error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'tuple'`

Code for reproducing the example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# sample data
df = {'Id' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
     'Category': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
      'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
      'Value1' :[50,200,2000,622,2,5,500,52,7,210,1000,4,600,212,510,-1005,2000,6,120,-50],
      'Value2' : [500,20,21,25,0,2,20,0,46,52,1,56,2500,24,89,52,50,5,125,20]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Id','Category', 'Gender', 'Value1', 'Value2'])





# function for flagging outliers
def outliers_iqr(column):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(column, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return np.where((column> upper_bound) | (column< lower_bound))


# remove outliers from Value1 column
Value1_Outliers_Removed = df[~df.groupby(['Category', 'Gender'])['Value1'].apply(outliers_iqr)]

# remove outliers from Value2 column
Value2_Outliers_Removed = df[~df.groupby(['Category', 'Gender'])['Value2'].apply(outliers_iqr)]
```

Could you please help me on how I can filter out these outliers and also if there is a quick way to count how many outliers were removed from each Category?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

delete `np.where` for having boolean format.

```
return (column> upper_bound) | (column< lower_bound)
```

then your reproducing code works wellll.